# Syntax coloring of html files in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

We use a custom cgi solution, which makes use of %-tags in html-files:

`<% keyword some.stuff() %>`

Does anyone know an easy way to get syntax coloring in eclipse for these tags?

Answer (score 2):

HTML syntax coloring settings are in:

`Preferences`-`Web`-`HTML files`-`Syntax coloring`

Just change and `apply` your changes, and take a look at the preview window below to see what part is changed.

The reason I don't list the specific location of the setting you want, is that I cannot figure out what kind of code you are writing in your project. HTML files can contain a variety type of contents, like java code in .jsp and javascript, so you may have to check other syntax coloring settings related to the type of code you use. For example, `.jsp` syntax coloring settings are in:

`Preferences`-`Web`-`JSP files`-`Syntax coloring`

But the effect can show in a `html` file.

You can search `syntax coloring` in Eclipse `Preferences` window to get a full list of such settings.

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be [Eclipse Colorer plug-in](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html). It is a very elegant plugin based on extensive Colorer library.